# Get nested documents with a filter on Elasticsearch 5

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have the following document mapped in ES 5:

```
{
   "appName" : {
      "mappings" : {
         "market_audit" : {
            "properties" : {
               "generation_date": {
                  "type": "date"
               },
               "customers" : {
                  "type" : "nested",
                  "properties" : {
                     "customer_id" : {
                        "type" : "integer"
                     },
   [... other properties ...]
}
```

Several entries in the "customers" node may have the same customer_id, and I am trying to retrieve only the entries having a specific customer_id (ie. "1") along with the "generation_date" of the top-level document (only the latest document is to be processed).

I was able to come up with the following query:

```
{
  "query": {},
  "sort": [
    { "generation_date": "desc" }
  ],
  "size": 1,
  "aggregations": {
    "nested": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "customers"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "filter": {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "customers.customer_id": {
                "query": "1"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "tophits_agg": {
              "top_hits": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query gets me the data I'm interested in, located in the "aggregations" array (along with the "hits" one that contains the whole document). The issue here is that the framework I use (ONGR's ElasticSearch bundle along with the DSL bundle, using Symfony3) complains every time I try to get access to the actual data that no buckets are available.

I've read the ES documentation but could not come up with a working query that added buckets. I'm sure I am missing something, a little help would be more than welcome. If you have an idea on how to appropriately modify the query I think I can come up with the PHP code to produce it.

EDIT: since this question got some views and no answer (and I'm still stuck), I would settle for any query that allows me to retrieve information about a specific "customer" (using customer_id) from the latest document generated (according to the "generation_date" field). The query I gave is just what I was able to come up with and I'm pretty sure there's a far better way to do that. Suggestions maybe ?

EDIT 2:
Here's the data sent to ES:

```
{
    "index": {
    "_type": "market_data_audit_document"
    }
}
{
    "customers": [
    {
        "customer_id": 1,
        "colocation_name": "colo1",
        "colocation_id": 26,
        "device_name": "device 1",
        "channels": [
        {
            "name": "channel1-5",
            "multicast":"1.2.1.5",
            "sugar_state":4,
            "network_state":1
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "customer_id":2,
        "colocation_name":"colo2",
        "colocation_id":27,
        "device_name":"device 2",
        "channels": [
        {
            "name":"channel2-5",
            "multicast":"1.2.2.5",
            "sugar_state":4,
            "network_state":1
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "customer_id":3,
        "colocation_name":"colo3",
        "colocation_id":28,
        "device_name":"device 3",
        "channels": [
        {
            "name":"channel3-5",
            "multicast":"1.2.3.5",
            "sugar_state":4,
            "network_state":1
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "customer_id":4,
        "colocation_name":"colo4",
        "colocation_id":29,
        "device_name":"device 4"
        ,"channels": [
        {
            "name":"channel4-5",
            "multicast":"1.2.4.5",
            "sugar_state":4,
            "network_state":1
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "customer_id":5,
        "colocation_name":"colo5",
        "colocation_id":30,
        "device_name":"device 5",
        "channels": [
        {
            "name":"channel5-5",
            "multicast":"1.2.5.5",
            "sugar_state":4,
            "network_state":1
        }
        ]
    }
    ],
    "generation_date":"2017-02-27T10:55:45+0100"
}
```

Unfortunately, when I tried to send the query listed in this post, I discovered that the aggregation does not do what I expected it to do: it returns "good" data, but from **ALL** the stored documents ! Here's an output example:

```
{
   "timed_out" : false,
   "took" : 60,
   "hits" : {
      "total" : 2,
      "hits" : [
         {
            "_source" : {
               "customers" : [
                  {
                     "colocation_id" : 26,
                     "channels" : [
                        {
                           "name" : "channel1-5",
                           "sugar_state" : 4,
                           "network_state" : 1,
                           "multicast" : "1.2.1.5"
                        }
                     ],
                     "customer_id" : 1,
                     "colocation_name" : "colo1",
                     "device_name" : "device 1"
                  },
                  {
                     "colocation_id" : 27,
                     "channels" : [
                        {
                           "multicast" : "1.2.2.5",
                           "network_state" : 1,
                           "name" : "channel2-5",
                           "sugar_state" : 4
                        }
                     ],
                     "customer_id" : 2,
                     "device_name" : "device 2",
                     "colocation_name" : "colo2"
                  },
                  {
                     "device_name" : "device 3",
                     "colocation_name" : "colo3",
                     "customer_id" : 3,
                     "channels" : [
                        {
                           "multicast" : "1.2.3.5",
                           "network_state" : 1,
                           "sugar_state" : 4,
                           "name" : "channel3-5"
                        }
                     ],
                     "colocation_id" : 28
                  },
                  {
                     "channels" : [
                        {
                           "sugar_state" : 4,
                           "name" : "channel4-5",
                           "multicast" : "1.2.4.5",
                           "network_state" : 1
                        }
                     ],
                     "customer_id" : 4,
                     "colocation_id" : 29,
                     "colocation_name" : "colo4",
                     "device_name" : "device 4"
                  },
                  {
                     "device_name" : "device 5",
                     "colocation_name" : "colo5",
                     "colocation_id" : 30,
                     "channels" : [
                        {
                           "sugar_state" : 4,
                           "name" : "channel5-5",
                           "multicast" : "1.2.5.5",
                           "network_state" : 1
                        }
                     ],
                     "customer_id" : 5
                  }
               ],
               "generation_date" : "2017-02-27T11:45:37+0100"
            },
            "_type" : "market_data_audit_document",
            "sort" : [
               1488192337000
            ],
            "_index" : "mars",
            "_score" : null,
            "_id" : "AVp_LPeJdrvi0cWb8CrL"
         }
      ],
      "max_score" : null
   },
   "aggregations" : {
      "nested" : {
         "doc_count" : 10,
         "filter" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "tophits_agg" : {
               "hits" : {
                  "max_score" : 1,
                  "total" : 2,
                  "hits" : [
                     {
                        "_nested" : {
                           "offset" : 0,
                           "field" : "customers"
                        },
                        "_score" : 1,
                        "_source" : {
                           "channels" : [
                              {
                                 "name" : "channel1-5",
                                 "sugar_state" : 4,
                                 "multicast" : "1.2.1.5",
                                 "network_state" : 1
                              }
                           ],
                           "customer_id" : 1,
                           "colocation_id" : 26,
                           "colocation_name" : "colo1",
                           "device_name" : "device 1"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "_source" : {
                           "colocation_id" : 26,
                           "customer_id" : 1,
                           "channels" : [
                              {
                                 "multicast" : "1.2.1.5",
                                 "network_state" : 1,
                                 "name" : "channel1-5",
                                 "sugar_state" : 4
                              }
                           ],
                           "device_name" : "device 1",
                           "colocation_name" : "colo1"
                        },
                        "_nested" : {
                           "offset" : 0,
                           "field" : "customers"
                        },
                        "_score" : 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "_shards" : {
      "total" : 13,
      "successful" : 1,
      "failures" : [
         {
            "reason" : {
               "index" : ".kibana",
               "index_uuid" : "bTkwoysSQ0y8Tt9yYFRStg",
               "type" : "query_shard_exception",
               "reason" : "No mapping found for [generation_date] in order to sort on"
            },
            "shard" : 0,
            "node" : "4ZUgOm4VRry6EtUK15UH3Q",
            "index" : ".kibana"
         },
         {
            "reason" : {
               "index_uuid" : "lN2mVF9bRjuDtiBF2qACfA",
               "index" : "archiv1_log",
               "type" : "query_shard_exception",
               "reason" : "No mapping found for [generation_date] in order to sort on"
            },
            "shard" : 0,
            "node" : "4ZUgOm4VRry6EtUK15UH3Q",
            "index" : "archiv1_log"
         },
         {
            "index" : "archiv1_session",
            "shard" : 0,
            "node" : "4ZUgOm4VRry6EtUK15UH3Q",
            "reason" : {
               "type" : "query_shard_exception",
               "index" : "archiv1_session",
               "index_uuid" : "cmMAW04YTtCb0khEqHpNyA",
               "reason" : "No mapping found for [generation_date] in order to sort on"
            }
         },
         {
            "shard" : 0,
            "node" : "4ZUgOm4VRry6EtUK15UH3Q",
            "reason" : {
               "reason" : "No mapping found for [generation_date] in order to sort on",
               "index" : "archiv1_users_dev",
               "index_uuid" : "AH48gIf5T0CXSQaE7uvVRg",
               "type" : "query_shard_exception"
            },
            "index" : "archiv1_users_dev"
         }
      ],
      "failed" : 12
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample document and a sample result you're getting and what data you're missing?

Comment: @val Good idea, did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Based on your description :

- you store documents on elasticsearch with a bunch of properties
- each document contains a list of customer within array (nested documents)
- you want to extract only nested document related to a customer.id
- your lib does not manage Elasticsearch response without buckets
- your are expecting Elasticsearch to return Nested Documents

### Problem

It exists 2 kind of aggregations :

- buckets
- metrics

In your case you ve 2 Aggregations under Nested Agg : Filter and Metric.
Filter :

- [Filter defines a single bucket of all the documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) but does not provide 'bucket' keyword on results.
- Top hits is a *Metric* and does not provides a bucket.

### workaround :

I doubt that your PHP lib will handle correctly the Nested aggregation result, but you could use Filter**s** instead of Filter Aggregations to get a bucket list

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "nested": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "customers"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "filters_customer": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "customers.customer_id": "1"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "top_hits_customer": {
              "top_hits": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Will provide something like :

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "nested": {
      "doc_count": 15,
      "filters_customer": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "doc_count": 3,
            "top_hits_customer": {
              "hits": {
                "total": 3,
                "max_score": 1,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "customers",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "customer_id": 1,
                      "foo": "bar"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "customers",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "customer_id": 1,
                      "foo": "bar"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "customers",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "customer_id": 1,
                      "foo": "bar"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Note on your EDIT 2

Elasticsearch will search over all documents, not on 'TOP 1' document based on your report date. A way to split your results by report is using term bucket on report date :

```
{
  "query": {},
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "grp_report": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "generation_date"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "nested_customers": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "customers"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "filters_customer": {
              "filters": {
                "filters": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "customers.customer_id": "1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "top_hits_customer": {
                  "top_hits": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Advices :

Avoid complex documents, prefer splitting your report in small documents with a related key (reportId for example). You will be able to filter and aggregate easily without any nested document. Add on customer document information on witch you will filter across all types (redundancy is not a problem in this case).

Use case examples :

- reports listing
- show customers information per reports
- show history for a customer across multiple reports

Current document example : /indexName/market_audit

```
{
  "generation_date": "...",
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "foo": "bar 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "foo": "bar 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "foo": "bar 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Reformated document :

/indexName/market_audit_report

```
{
  "report_id" : "123456"
  "generation_date": "...",
  "foo":"bar"
}
```

/indexName/market_audit_customer documents

```
{
  "report_id" : "123456"
  "customer_id": 1,
  "foo": "bar 1"
}


{
  "report_id" : "123456"
  "customer_id": 2,
  "foo": "bar 2"
}


{
  "report_id" : "123456"
  "customer_id": 3,
  "foo": "bar 3"
}
```

If you know your report id you will be able to get all your data in one request :

- a filter on report id
- a term aggregation on type

  - a filter on type report

    - a top_hit aggregation to get report
  - a filter aggregation to get only type customer and customer id 1

    - a top_hit aggregation to customer 1 info

Or

- a filter on report id
- a term aggregation on type

  - a filter on type report

    - a top_hit aggregation to get report
  - a term aggregation on customer id

    - a top_hit aggregation to retrieve information per customer

### Top Hits Aggregation Size

Do not forget to provide a `size` in your top_hits otherwise you will get only the [top 3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_options_2)

Answer (score 0):

Reading elasticsearch first line of [aggregations definition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) I think that you don't understand well how it works:

> The aggregations framework helps provide aggregated data based on a
>   search query

Since your query hasn't any filter at all, *returning **ALL** the stored documents* in `hits.hits` objects is the expected result.
Then you use a `filter` aggregation that helps you to get desired documents, but they are in `aggs` property of returned `dict`
If I'm right, I'd recommend you to keep it as simple as you can, so here's my guessed query

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "nested": {
                "path" : "customers",
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must" : [
                            "term": {"customer_id" : "1"}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "tophits_agg": {
      "top_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input ! 2 notes though, the query you propose is not suitable for ES 5 (filtered as been deprecated), and the "[]" for the "must" node should be "{}" :) This aside, the query seems to do the job but @bloublou's comment made me realize that his refactoring proposal could help me provide better, on-the-side, information (evolution over time mainly). Guess I'll go this way. But your clarification regarding the aggregations helped me  :)